# Is there any method to standarize time series data?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, standardization

I want to do time series cluster analysis by using hclust or tsclust.

My data is GRDP data by year for a region.

the data is look like

area_name    2012  2013  2014   2015  2016  2017  2018 ..

area _ A    value  value value  value value value value

area _ B    value  value value  value value value value

area _ C    value  value value  value value value value
.
.
.

However, my data has too wide of a range.
Each area has significant differences.
for instance, area_ A is around 50000~ 55000.
but area_C is around 3000~4000.

in this case, which scaling method do I have to use?
I think 3 methods will be possible.

in case of Standardization, (z-score)

**1. grand mean method**
mean for all data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfk18.png)

**2. year mean method**
mean for each year

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvuqu.png)

**3. area mean method**
mean for each area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r4k5.png)

which method will be possible and statistically valid ?

I need help. Thank you

Comment: [A word on standardization in longitudinal studies: don't](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4569815/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.